# how to create popup window with javascript in output link attribute in visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

how to create popup window with javascript in output link attribute in visualforce page in salesforce. let me know

Comment: please give more detail in this question. @mmix has given as detailed an answer as possible given the vagueness of the question. It's hard to help more without you giving some more context as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

VisualForce is not just apex tags, it's HTML + apex namespace, so anything you can use in a html you can use here. One way to do this is by regular `<a>` tag

```
<a href="javascript: window.open(...);">{!someApexProperty}</a>
```

the way to do similar thing with apex tag is

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!someApexProperty}" onclick="window.open(...); return false;" />
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment For your problem you can use the following:

```
<a style="font-weight:bold" href="javascript: window.open('/{!row.id}/e?retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}');">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

Comment: <apex:outputLink title="" value="/{!row.id}/e?retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}" style="font-weight:bold">Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;  i want using this this code create popup box in visualforce page please let me know mmix.